# Multiple stores, dynamic domains problem

Tags: cache, multistore, url

In a new site, with multiple domains, I have a problem. First the several websites with their own store view:

```
shop.mydomain.org, code shop
retail.mydomain.org, code retail
*.mydomain.org, code base
```

The base_url for all these stores is set to `{{base_url}}` since the last one is dynamic. In a `.htaccess` file, the code is set, ie:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop.mydomain.*$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website,E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:shop] [L]
```

When visiting ie `shop.mydomain.org` the first time after clearing the cache, everything works fine. The base_url is set to `shop.mydomain.org`. Without clearing the cache and continueing on `shop.mydomain.org`, the base_url is still okay.

Still without clearing the cache, when I visit `retail.mydomain.org`, there is a problem with the base_url. On this domain, the base_url is the same as for `shop.mydomain.org`, when I would expect it to change to `retail.mydomain.org`.

I know I can change the base_url in the configuration to `shop.mydomain.org` and `retail.mydomain.org` solving my problem for these 2 domains. But, the last domain (`*.mydomain.org`), can't be set to a specific base_url. All must work with a template in which an image is loaded based on the * part in the domain.

What I've tried:

In `Mage_Core_Model_Store->getBaseUrl()`, change line

```
$this->_baseUrlCache[$cacheKey] = rtrim($url, '/') . '/';
```

to

```
return rtrim($url, '/') . '/';
```

to prevent Magento from adding the url in cache.

And more or less the same in `Mage_Core_Model_Website::getConfig()`; don't store the config value in cache if the path contains 'url'.

Both options didn't work. Does someone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `{{base_url}}` as value for base url. It can lead to security issues.
Edit the configuration for each website from `System->Configuration->Web` and set the base url accordingly: `http://shop.mydomain.org/`, `http://retail.mydomain.org/` and `http://mydomain.org/`.
Clear the cache and give it a go.
I don't think you need the last one to be dynamic. Or maybe I'm missing something.
If you insist on working with different URLs (dynamic) for one website, I think you will have a problem. For example most block cache files depend on the store id (for example the main menu), and if the cache is created with one URL when accessing with a different url you will get the cached data with the first URL.
Maybe you should rethink your business logic here.